# Tomcat JNDIRealms like authentication on Apache HTTP Web Server

Tags: tomcat, webserver

In tomcat the container security can be enabled by using JNDIRealm for certain roles defined in LDAP. Can a similar objective be achieved by using only Apache HTTP Web Server and without a container like Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to this one.

If you have to configure Apache to authenticate against LDAP similar to JNDIRealm in Tomcat, following needs to be configured in Apache web server. Once this is done, only people in group `Application.Users` will have to access to application!

```
<VirtualHost 10.199.137.19:80>
ServerName application.company.com
ServerAlias app
<Location /> 
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic 
AuthBasicProvider ldap file
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on 
AuthLDAPBindDN anonymous 
AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.company.com:3268/DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com?SamAccountName?sub?   (objectCategory=*)
Require ldap-group cn=Application.Users,OU=Application,OU=Groups,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com
Require valid-user  
AuthUserFile "/company/apps/apache/conf/wtpasswd"
</Location>
```